# upgrade from postgresql 9.3 to 10

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I've made several unsuccessful attempts to upgrade from posgtres 9.3 to 10 using the pg_upgradecluster command... the ver 10 instance is installed and up and running side-by-side with the 9.3 instance, I drop the ver 10 instance, stop the 9.3 instance and issue the upgrade command to it... it runs for 2+ hours (I have a couple databases in the 9.3 cluster, some fairly large) and then fails with the following error(s):

1. "Upgrading database ...
   pg_restore: [archiver (db)] error returned by PQputCopyData: server closed the connection unexpectedly
       This probably means the server terminated abnormally
       before or while processing the request.
   Re-enabling connections to the old cluster...
   Re-enabling connections to the new cluster...
   Error during cluster dumping, removing new cluster
2. "could not send data to client: Connection reset by peer"
3. "connection to client lost"

Is there something I'm missing and/or doing wrong? I see a couple folks have performed this upgrade sequence successfully...

Thank you for any insights...

Comment: I'd suggesting either on dba.stackexchange.com or superuser.com. Unfortunately it's off-topic here, as it's not a programming question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon -- thanks... my bad....